# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC) error

Tags: c#, excel, com, vsto

I'm getting error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC)

for my below C# code, I'm trying to save a worksheet here,

But the same works in a local environment: Office 2010, Windows 2003

Not Working on the server: Office 2003, Windows 2003

Code:

```
wBook = xCel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelPath);                
wSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);                    
wSheet.Copy(Type.Missing, Type.Missing);                    
wSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wBook.Sheets[1];
wSheet.SaveAs(ExcelCopyPath);
```

What's wrong here? It's failing while saving it.
In some other server, it`ll save but with macro in it which I dont want.

To sample follow error picture

[image]

Comment: What for do you sleep thread? Why do you release com object twice?

Comment: Your empty catch block will swallow any exceptions, and make it difficult to figure out what's going wrong! Can you debug on your server?

Answer (score 2):

Its not good practice to use office automation on server, you may consider alternative like epplus.

For your problem office 2003 required Microsoft.Office.Excel version 11 and office 2010 will need version 14 . I guess in your project you would have added version 14 hence it worked with word 2010 but didn't worked on server with office 2003

try late binding http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302902, if that solves your prpoblem, count it as iterop issue

Comment: I've deployed applications written with 2010 on my dev machine to computers running 2007 before with no issues, I suspect it's because the OP is trying to do something which works in 2010, but not in 2003, but the empty catch blocks make it impossible to see what's going wrong!

Comment: what's the version of interop you are referencing in your project?

Comment: @BrijeshMishra: It`s "1.3.0.0" version as specified in VS2010.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that office automation is not necessarilly the best solution - I found NPOI via nuget a much easier solution to implement

Comment: but EPPLUS does not support excel 2003 ?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use belov code what I wrote. I tried in another project. and it's working

**EDIT :**

probably the cause of your error is your excel version is different from what you used in code.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(); 
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue); 
xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);    

xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "xxx";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "yyy";


xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A7").Borders.Weight = 2;
xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A7").Font.Bold = true;
xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A7").Font.Size = 13;

xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A2", "A7").Borders.Weight = 2;
xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A2", "A7").Font.Bold = true;
xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A2", "A7").Font.Size = 13;

xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "B9").ColumnWidth = 25;



xlWorkBook.SaveAs(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\exceller\\6 Nolu sosyal ve kültürel faaliyetler\\" +
    txtFaaliyetAdi.Text + ".xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue
, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);


xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue); 
xlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: EFE: Thanks for the answer, but my problem is it`s saving it,but wit macro in it. Why is it so? I dont want macro to be available

Answer (score 0):

It 'a permission problem when IIS is running
I had this problem and I solved it in this way

I went on folders

**C:\Windows\ System32\config\SystemProfile**

and

**C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\SystemProfile**

are protected system folders, they usually have the lock.

Right-click-> Card security-> Click on Edit-> Add untente "Autenticadet User" and assign permissions.

At this point everything is solved, if you still have problems try to give all permissions to "Everyone"